# SharePoint Low trust Provider Hosted Add-in access denied to host web, the remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: web-services, oauth

**Brief of what I am trying to achieve:** 
Would like to create root folder properties for a list thats in SharePoint online host web from a remote web service hosted in azure web app.

**Have the hybrid set-up as below:**

1. SharePoint Hosted Add-in
2. Azure Web app - Provider hosted add-in which has wcf service.
3. Registered my remote add-in using http:///_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx form.
4. Have the client ID & client secret by registering add-in.
5. updated the add-in manifest xml with the above client id & add-in web config with above client id & client secret.

From the SharePoint hosted add-in page on button click, I am able to call the published remote wcf service end point with parameters (hostWebUrl, listId, propKey, propValue).

Created a client context = new clientcontext(hostWebUrl), how ever I get 403 forbidden error at this point.

All the web sources suggest to get contexttoken, but since this is a wcf service there is no HTTPRequest instead have the requestcontext.

How do I get the contexttoken and authenticate the host web using oAuth?

Any help with this & a working example would be highly appreciated.

Many Thanks,
Shan

Comment: Just to add on for the above issue: I have been trying to get a new context token by doing a post request for url - https://<SPHostUrl>/_layouts/15/AppRedirect.aspx?client_id=<app registered client id>&redirect_uri=<encoded wcf service end point url>, the above request is happening in the hosted app js on a button click. However when I debug I get error "The remote server returned the following error while establishing a connection - Forbidden"

Comment: Apologise, for this post in first place. I am able to resolve the above issue by having correct scope in the appmanifest.xml. I was pointing the scope to hostweb url instead of the string literal like this: <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologise for this post in first place. I am able to resolve the above issue by having the correct scope in the appmanifest.xml. I was pointing the scope to hostweb url instead of the correct string literal like this:

```
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web"; Right="FullControl" />
```

Comment: Hey, can you update your answer properly please, I am also facing same issue.

Comment: Hello Mihir, In my case I did a simple human error by wrongly typing the string literal for the add-in scope in AppPermissionRequest element in the AppManifest.xml. Please see the post: https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/add-in-permissions-in-sharepoint . Hope this helps. Cheers